# Java Convert Byte[] into Blob

Tags: java, encryption, blob

I know there has been many posts on how to do this, but I have tried their solutions and every time I am getting an error making me unable to compile and I'm not sure why. These are the solutions I have tried.

```
        Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes); 
        //next try
        Blob b = new SerialBlob(byteData);
```

error message is always change type of blob to Serial blob. If I change it to serial blob I get an error message saying string is too long for column.

If I use code

```
        byte[] byteData = encodedImg.getBytes("UTF-8");//Better to specify encoding
        Blob blobs = (Blob) pprepo.createBlob();
       blobs.setBytes(1, byteData);
```

I get the error message

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Blob, at table: post, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(image)]

And this is my class

```
    private Blob image;

   public Blob getImage(String string) {
   return image;
   }

   public void setImage(Blob image) {
   this.image = image;
   }
```

So I'm not sure where else to go on here, as nothing seems to be working. Just in case I am using repositories as my DB connection and I am trying to save a user inputted multipart file into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the size of the column in the database. Seems like its set to something like `varbinary(100)` and you're attempting to post something thats got a byte length greater than the field limit. Eg. you're field is a `varbinary(124)`. Hence the error??

Comment: I have changed the column to varbinary(124) and after converting it to Serialblob I'm still getting the error. I used a print statement and the length of the Serialblob is apparently 6?